# Python - Why are all my objects inheriting from other objects

Tags: python, class, object, inheritance

the following code which is pretty self-explanatory for anyone who has watched Harry Potter:

```
class House():


    def __init__(self, name, color, founder, head, animal, element, traits=[], members=[]):
        self.name = name
        self.founder = founder
        self.color = color
        self.head = head
        self.animal = animal
        self.element = element
        self.traits = traits
        self.members = members

    def SortingHat(self, name, *traits):
        if name not in self.members:
            for trait in traits:
                if trait in self.traits:
                    print("Welcome to {}".format(self.name))
                    self.members.append(name)
                    break
                else:
                    print("Not a {}".format(self.name))
        else:
            print("Already a {}".format(self.name))



Gryffindor = House("Gryffindor", "Scarlet and Gold", "Godric Gryffindor", "Minerva McGonagall", "Lion", "Fire", ["Courage", "Bravery", "Determination", "Daring", "Nerve", "Chivalry"])

Hufflepuff = House("Hufflepuff", "Yellow and Black", "Helga Hufflepuff", "Pomona Sprout", "Badget", "Earth", ["Hard-working", "Patience", "Fairness", "Just", "Loyalty", "Modesty"])

Ravenclaw = House("Ravenclaw", "Blue and Bronze", "Rowena Ravenclaw", "Filius Flitwick", "Eagle", "Air", ["Wit", "Learning", "Wisdom", "Acceptance", "Intelligence", "Creativity"])

Slytherin = House("Slytherin", "Green and Silver", "Salazar Slytherin", "Severus Snape", "Serpent", "Water", ["Resourcefulness", "Pride", "Cunning", "Ambition", "Self-preservation"])
```

Now when I run:

```
Gryffindor.SortingHat("Harry Potter", "Determination")
`Welcome to Gryffindor`

Gryffindor.members
['Harry Potter']
```

But then when I do

```
Slytherin.members
['Harry Potter']
```

Why is Slytherin.members giving me Harry Potter when I didn't even call the method on Slytherin object

Comment: All your objects share the same `traits` and `members` lists, since they're using the default value.

Comment: How do I avoid this?

Comment: See the linked question.